# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'function'

Tags: python, typeerror

I've been working on this for a few days and got it 'kind of' working, but couldn't get the whole programme to function and every time I change something there's another error! I'd really appreciate your help on this one.

What I want to achieve:

- Write a function that takes the distance travelled (in miles) as its only parameter and returns the total fare as its only result.
- Write a main program that demonstrates the function. Hint: fares change over time, depending on the surge of users.
- Use values in the function to represent the base fare and the variable portion of the fare so that the program can be updated easily when the rates increase.

Basically the driver needs to enter the distance, and whether there is surge pricing, and it needs to come back with a final fare.

Here's the code:

```
# The base fare for an Uber trip
base_fare = 2.50      

# Additional price for every mile, this will be multiplied by distance travelled
extra_fare = 1.25

surge_increase = (float(input("Please enter how much your current surge pricing is: ")))

# Find if there is any surge pricing going and how much it is
def surge_fare(distance_in_miles):
   total_surgefare = base_fare + (surge_increase * distance_in_miles)
   return total_surgefare()

# Creates a function that determines the total fare by adding the base fare to the extra fare according to how
# far has been travelled
def uber_fare(distance_in_miles):
   total_fare = base_fare + (extra_fare * distance_in_miles)
   return total_fare()

   
if total_surgefare <= str(0):
   while True:
       try:
           total_fare = uber_fare(float(input("Please enter how many miles you have driven on this ride: ")))
       except ValueError:
           print("That's not a number. Please enter how many miles you have driven on this ride. ")
       else:
           print("Your total fare is £%.2f" % total_fare)
           break

if total_surgefare > str(0):
   while True:
       try:
           total_surgefare = surge_fare(float(input("Please enter how many miles you have driven on this ride: ")))
       except ValueError:
           print("That's not a number. Please enter how many miles you have driven on this ride. ")
       else:
           print("Your total fare is £%.2f" % total_surgefare)
```

The error I get is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-6d5f49e9b1ab> in <module>
     19 
     20 
---> 21 if int(0) <= total_surgefare:
     22     while True:
     23         try:

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'function'
I have tried lots of different approaches, maybe I'm using the wrong function even. I added int(0) thinking it would help, obvs not. It is not 100% complete as I want to fix this error before moving on.
```

Comment: The posted code is inconsistent with the stack trace (there is no `int(0)` in the posted code).

Comment: Please don't delete your code

Answer (score 2):

While defining the `surge_fare` function you return `total_surgefare()` the parentheses at the end try to call it as a function so instead do `return total_surgefare` (similarly change the `return total_fare()` part in the `uber_fare` function)

Comment: yes but it isn't defined as a function at the beginning its defined as an integer so the fix should still work. yes agreed i've edited the answer

Comment: This doesn't explain the error OP is seeing.  It needs to be fixed, but OP is getting an actual function for `total_surgefare`.  Unfortunately, the posted code does not match the stack trace so there's no telling what OP is actually doing.

Comment: That's a totally different error, not the error the question is about.

Comment: yup the functions aren't called so it would be helpful if OP posted the whole code

Comment: Thanks, that actually is the whole code, because I don't know what I'm doing. I've been learning for 6 weeks. I appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you did not define the total surge fare. Please Define the variable:

```
    # The base fare for an Uber trip
base_fare = 2.50

# Additional price for every mile, this will be multiplied by distance travelled
extra_fare = 1.25

surge_increase = (float(
    input("Please enter how much your current surge pricing is: ")))


# Find if there is any surge pricing going and how much it is
def surge_fare(distance_in_miles):
    total_surgefare = base_fare + (surge_increase * distance_in_miles)
    return total_surgefare


# Creates a function that determines the total fare by adding the base fare to the extra fare according to how
# far has been travelled
def uber_fare(distance_in_miles):
    total_fare = base_fare + (extra_fare * distance_in_miles)
    return total_fare

# ASSING VALUE TO total_surgefare according to your need
total_surgefare = surge_fare(float(input("Please enter how many miles you have driven on this ride: ")))
if total_surgefare <= 0:
    while True:
        try:
            total_fare = uber_fare(
                float(
                    input(
                        "Please enter how many miles you have driven on this ride: "
                    )))
        except ValueError:
            print(
                "That's not a number. Please enter how many miles you have driven on this ride. "
            )
        else:
            print("Your total fare is £%.2f" % total_fare)
            break

if total_surgefare > 0:
    while True:
        try:
            total_surgefare = surge_fare(
                float(
                    input(
                        "Please enter how many miles you have driven on this ride: "
                    )))
        except ValueError:
            print(
                "That's not a number. Please enter how many miles you have driven on this ride. "
            )
        else:
            print("Your total fare is £%.2f" % total_surgefare)
```

Assign total surge variable value according to your need.
NOTE:
I ADDED THE COMMENT "    # ASSING VALUE TO total_surgefare according to your need"
Assign the value to the variable below that comment

Comment: Sorry, not quite clear on what you mean. I tried this (with your comment because I'm not sure what to change) and the programme doesn't seem to end!